# Can I Bluetooth tether my Android to iPhone?

Tags: bluetooth, tethering, ios, bluetooth-tethering

I am very confused atm. My iPhone 4 says it has Internet Tethering (Settings > General > Network > Internet Tethering > On) via Bluetooth (Settings > General > Bluetooth > On).

1. Does this mean I can share my data plan with my Android phone? (A Dell Streak.)
2. When I activate Bluetooth on my Android phone (Settings > Wireless & Network settings > Bluetooth > turn on > Bluetooth Settings > Discoverable > turn on) I can both iPhone and Streak to see each other; I get the dialog saying "confirm that number xx appears on the other device's screen" and press the button to confirm that; but that's it. From then on both devices say:

   > Paired but not connected.

   ### What else do I need to do?

While researching for a solution, I found that a lot of posts I see on the Mac forums say that your provider (currently Virgin Australia) must support tethering. Does that cover this use? How do I know if my supplier is stopping tethering from working?

<sup>If relevant my Android version is 2.2.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use BT-DUN on the streak unless there is something custom built into the UI.  My Archos 70 has a setting baked into Android for Bluetooth Tethering specifically.  Without that or some app to enable it, the Streak won't know where to get the internet connection from, even if the devices are connected.  Don't bother with PDANet because it only works when you are going the other way, sharing your Android internet connection with another device.

Another option, would be to **put MyWi on your iPhone and make it a wireless access point**, then you can connect to it via your wifi connection.  There is one problem: the MyWi creates an adhoc connection and Android doesn't recognize adhoc.  You can get around this by editing your wpa_supplicant file but you need to be rooted to do this.  Here are the instructions to do this: http://android.modaco.com/content/dell-streak-streak-modaco-com/316049/ad-hoc-network-connection-for-streak/

Comment: This sounds like something I need to root my device for right?

Comment: How about this - I am only using the data connection on my iPhone until my new account activates on the Dell Streak (with Optus directly). Is it easier to set up the Dell Streak (as a WiFi hot-spot?) so that the iPhone can use its data plan?

Comment: Good question.  I'm not sure.  I don't know if the Streak supports the native hotspot capability of Froyo (even if it does you'll probably have to pay your carrier extra).  Otherwise, you'll probably still need to root your Streak to use an app like Wifi Tether or Barnacle. Those, like MyWi, create an adhoc hotspot. Do some googling and find out if the iPhone can connect to an adhoc connection.  I believe it can, but I'm not sure.