# Can I tether iPhone 3G to EEE Pad Transformer?

Tags: tethering, ios

This is somewhat simmilar to [Can I Bluetooth tether my Android to iPhone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4234/can-i-bluetooth-tether-my-android-to-iphone), but since it is 7 months old and belongs to different Android version, I will ask again.

I want to buy EEE Pad Transformer (which comes with Honeycomb) and I want to tether it with my iPhone 3G, which supports only Bluetooth tethering. Will that be possible? (I will clarify - I want to tether the 3G connection, that I have on iPhone, to EEE Pad)

I know that the question is half about iPhone, but I think it is more about Android, since I know bluetooth tethering works on iPhone 3G end, I just want to know if it will work on recieving end on EEE Pad Transformer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tethering an iOS device to an android device will cause a wormhole to open and suck them both in. I don't recommend it.

[the non-sarcastic response to bt tethering on honeycomb](http://forums.androidcentral.com/motorola-xoom/63969-how-bluetooth-tether-android-phone-xoom-no-root-app-required.html)